# Calling RaspiStill from C program using WiringPi

Tags: camera

I am trying to create a C program that would call RaspiStill or RaspiVid when one of the GPIO's is triggered high. I would like it into fit into this program that I have already created...

```
include <stdlib.h>
include <stdio.h>
include <wiringPi.h>

define LED 0
define SWITCH 1

int main (void)
{
wiringPiSetup ();

pinMode (LED,OUTPUT);

pinMode (LED,OUTPUT);

while (1)
{
if (digitalRead (SWITCH)==1)
{
    digitalWrite (LED,0);
}
else
    digitalWrite (LED,1);
}
return 0;
}
```

I would like to call raspistill when digital read is 1 (when GPIO is high).

I understand I might be able to use the `system()` command?

Any help would be awesome!!!

Comment: You don't want to call `system()` to run things outside your program.  That is what you consider as your last option, because it is so inefficient and "volatile".

Comment: yeah, it does not seem to be functioning as i thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to run another executable using C on linux: `system()` and `exec()`, although `exec()` isn't really a function, it's a group of functions, `execl()`, `execv()` etc.  They all have the same man page, so you can see the list via e.g. `man execl`.

`system()` is fine if what you want to do is launch another application and *wait for it to finish,* and you don't need to interact with or gather output from the other process.

If the context is that you don't want to wait for the other process to finish -- i.e., you want your program to go on running and RaspiStill to work in the background -- you need to combine `exec()` and `fork()`.  The `exec()` functions *replace the current process with a new one*.  In other words, `exec()` never returns; it's the last line of your code that will execute.

This is why you want to  combine it with `fork()`, which creates a child process.  You then call `exec()` in the child (note there is no main function here yet):

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fprintf()
#include <unistd.h>  // fork(), exec()
#include <string.h>  // strerror()
#include <errno.h>   // errno
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit()

void forkAndExecute (const char *path, char *const args[]) {
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        fprintf ( stderr,
            "fork() failed: %s",
            strerror(errno)
        );
        return;
    }
    if (pid != 0) return;
// If pid == 0, this is the child process.
    if (execvp(path, args) == -1) {
        fprintf ( stderr,
            "execvp(%s) failed: %s %s",
            path, strerror(errno)
        );
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

If you haven't used `fork()` before, you need to understand that because it literally forks the program into two, after `fork()` you have TWO programs running, the parent and the child.  In the parent program, `fork()` will have returned the PID of the child process (if it returns -1, it failed, and there is no child; this shouldn't normally happen).  In the child program, it will have returned 0.  So you can use this to create two diverging branches of execution -- the parent does one thing while the child does another:

```
int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *const args[] = { "ls", "-l", "/" };
    forkAndExecute("ls", args);
    puts("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

What will *probably* happen when you run this is something like:

```
me@home» ./a.out
Hello world
me@home» total 76
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root     7 May 22  2012 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   6 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:48 boot
drwxr-xr-x   18 root root  3300 Dec  3 14:26 dev
[...]
```

Notice "Hello world" appeared *first*, then the program seemed to end (which is why the prompt came back), then the output from `ls` appeared.  I said this is *probably* what will happen because it could have been the other way around -- those are two programs running simultaneously, so who does what first is indeterminate (but in this case the parent will *probably* be quicker to output).

Note it is generally not good to have the parent finish before a child does, if that is a concern see `man 2 waitpid`.

Two things I want to point out about the use of `exec()`;

1. The first arg to those functions is always the path to the executable.  Since `ls` is probably in `$PATH`, I just used `"ls"`.  The next arg (or in the case of `execvp`, the first element in the 2nd arg array) should be the *name* of the executable.  This is actually the same as the first arg in the arg array passed to a program's `main()` function -- it's always the name of the program executable itself.  Most programs don't make any use of this, so it can probably be anything; I used `"ls"` again:

   ```
   char *const args[] = { "ls", "-l", "/" };
   forkAndExecute("ls", args);
   ```

   So using, e.g., `execl()`;

   ```
       execl("ls", "ls", "-l", "/");
   ```

   If the executable isn't in `$PATH`, put the path in the first arg (`"/bin/ls"`) but not in the second.
2. `exec()` doens't return *unless* it fails, which can happen if it can't find the path you've specified.  That's why there's an `exit()` in the last `if` clause of `forkAndExecute()`.

If you want to send data to the child process's standard input, or read from its output, you need to use `fork()`, `exec()`, and `pipe()` to connect the child's file descriptors to something the parent can read from/write to.

BTW, general C questions are better off on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  `fork()` and `execute()` actually aren't standard C, they're POSIX (hence, `unistd.h`), but any C programmer who didn't grow up in a cave is probably aware of them.